# Simple RegExp matches what it shouldn't

Tags: regex

I'm writing a text formatter that needs to clear out special characters from Chinese pinyins and replace them with their latin counterparts. But I've suddenly stumbled upon this problem
So, let's say I have this syllable

```
shu
```

I need to check if it contains one letter of the list below:

```
üǖǘǚǚü̆ǜ
```

I have a RegExp like this
`[üǖǘǚǚü̆ǜ]{1}`

It shouldn't match simple "u" but it does.

[image]

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use non-capturing group with each character separately:

```
(?:ü|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǚ|ü̆|ǜ){1}
```

Seems working.

Comment: Indeed it does help :) Thank you! I can accept your answer in 5 minutes

Comment: and as others said here `{1}` is redundant

Answer (score 6):

Most of those graphemes consist of multiple code points, one of which is the letter 'u'. A character class in Unicode-aware regex engines is a class of code points, not graphemes, so this character class will match any of the code points contained within it, including the letter 'u'.

As far as I'm aware no regex engine provides anything like a "grapheme class", so your only option is an alternation (i.e. `ü|ǖ|ǘ|...`).

PS: `{1}` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. {1} is not required for this particular case but required in my formatter. It needs to find exactly  one occurence

Comment: @Konstantin `{1}` is always redundant. There is no scenario where adding `{1}` to a pattern changes its behavior in any way.

Comment: You're right, of course :) I'm just a bit tired and thinking slow already :D

Answer (score 1):

It Seems that some special u letters you're using includes the u matching.
I've found this workaround:

```
[üǖǘǚǚü̆ǜ](?<!u)
```

Using a negative lookbehind that doesn't match the normal "u" letter.

Link to test: https://regex101.com/r/U1N2Z9/1

Comment: This will also match the decorations in "ä̌" for example. Plus, it will produce more matches than expected and if you use it to replace the matching characters, you'll still have "u"s left over (e.g. `"üǖǘǚǚü̆ǜ".replaceAll("[üǖǘǚǚü̆ǜ](?<!u)", "")` will return "uu" rather than "").